# Assgin label "pro" on switch

Tags: android, android-switch

I'm new to android programming. I want to customize the `switch` like below figure.

[image]

And also I want to control the spaces between text and switch.

What changes I have to add pro label on my switch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own Switch style. For example:

```
<Switch
              android:id="@+id/switch1"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              app:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_switch_inner_holo_light"
              app:track="@drawable/apptheme_switch_track_holo_light"  //This is what you need to customize with your own drawable that has "pro" on it
              app:textOn="ON"
              app:textOff="OFF
              />
```

Use xml attributes like margins, padding, alignment and so on to play with the spacing